# automatically place images according to the space available in a div

Tags: html, css

My question is this: in a div (example height 500px, width 500px) if i insert two images of greater width than the div, one of the two is placed in the row below. But if I then insert a third image of reduced dimensions that can fit in the first line instead it is placed after the second image. How can i position the images according to the space available in the div? so that the large images will be placed in another row while the smaller ones will occupy the spaces left free. I should do it without manually changing the order of the images in the html. One last thing, the images must all be merged without spaces. thanks to those who will answer me

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0):

This is quite simple in javascript/jquery if its worth the trouble.  You can get the width of all the images and then add them up and index them then math >500...  jquery target the images loop through them with an each then logic and indexing--image1 width=300 image2=300 image 3 = 100, image4 = 100...

Once theyre all indexed if total < 500 then next kind of thing.  If you know jquery and js this should make sense to you, if not, you probably wont be able to write it and maybe should move on.